# How to trigger AWS Gluejob through AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I am learning about a wonderful tool called AWS Cloudformation and I am having a hard time finding resources to find how to trigger AWS Gluejob via SQS.

I learnt about Glue Triggers from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/about-triggers.html). How do I trigger a gluejob whenever something is dumped in SQS?

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no possibility of SQS triggering a Glue job directly.

What you could do though, is writing a Lambda function, [which gets triggered by your SQS.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html)

In this Lambda function you could call the Glue SDK to start your Glue Job.

Comment: another alternative is to use AWS step functions but one would need to use S3 events to trigger the state machine