# Execute only one Glue job at a time / sequential Glue job execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

Currently, we have the following AWS setup for executing Glue jobs. An S3 event triggers a lambda function execution whose python logic triggers 10 AWS Glue jobs.

S3 -> Trigger -> Lambda -> 1 or more Glue Jobs.

With this setup, we see that at a time, multiple different Glue jobs run in parallel. How can I make it so that at any point in time, only one Glue job runs? And any Glue jobs sent for execution wait in a queue until the currently running Glue job is finished?

Comment: how are the glue jobs being triggered from Lambda? By passing the glue Job name?  If so, can you not restrict it to one single glue job? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652485/how-to-trigger-glue-etl-pyspark-job-through-s3-events-or-aws-lambda/57655429#57655429.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for having some job queues to have the Glue jobs trigger in sequence, you may consider using a combination of SQS->lambda->Glue jobs?  [Please refer this SO for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67431180/how-to-trigger-aws-gluejob-through-aws-sqs)

AWS Step function is also another option as suggested by Vaquar Khan

Answer (score 1):

You can use step function and in each steps specify job you want to run so you will have control to run jobs and once step one complete then call step 2 jobs etc